# App in Open Testing phase on Play Store can't be accessed

Tags: android, google-play

I have an app that already have had several releases pushed to the Open Testing track:

[image]

The earliest release was 22 hours ago and the latest, 2 hours ago. However, no one seems to be able to access the app with either links provided here:
[image]

The first link for joining on Android shows this:
[image]

The second link, for joining on the web, prompts me to sign-in to my google account, and then shows this:
[image]

However, people that were originally in my internal testing email list *can* access the app from the first link, *but not* the second link. I am also able to download, install and run the app from the first link on my Android Emulator (using my own google account which is in the internal testing email list).

I've tried adding new users to my internal testing email list, but that didn't allow them to access the Open Testing release.

I've also tried pausing the internal testing track, but that did nothing. I have read elsewhere that the open testing app will only be available after a few hours, but the first release has already been released 22 hours ago.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see there it says "In review", you should expect them to review and approve it since there are many cases of misuse of apps in the Play Store.
[image]

Comment: none of the previous releases have been approved yet though... how do I know the review progress? And is it possible to get them to skip the previous releases?

Comment: I had the same problem and today I activate the app in the play store.

Comment: it’s been 44 hours total and it’s still “In review”…

Comment: I had to wait 5 days for them to activate it.

Comment: alright then, thanks for sharing

Answer (score 0):

You can see the status in "Go to Publication Summary":

[image]

Comment: The page doesn't seem to show anything about the review progress... it just says "Rollout started"

Comment: It didn't appear before, it appeared today after my app was approved in the play store, despite the fact that it is still under review.